# Is space complexity of splay tree is O(1) or O(n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

When compared to AVL, Redblack trees, I think the splay tree does not store any extra information bits but why did the wiki mention space complexity as O(n) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree and also the https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/ mentions O(n). Is it because of stack recursion space during elements traversal/splaying or am I missing anything? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: O(1) would mean that the tree has the same size no matter how many elements there are. Does that seem right?

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry I did not get you. what I mean is we don't require any extra space to do splaying, unlike AVL that requires a balance factor and red back requires for red/black coloring.

Comment: O(n) just means that if you have twice as many items, the tree has double the size.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I understand the definitions of O(1) and O(n) but could you please tell why the splay tree has space complexity as O(n)?

Comment: Because, if there are twice as many items, the tree has double the size.